# Anyone know of a simple WPF/Silverlight data access framework?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-access

Does anyone know of a simple WPF or Silverlight framework which enables you to e.g. define some database tables in e.g. SQL Server compact database and then the framework automatically creates the Window classes etc. which allows a user to login and edit that data?

I'm not looking for a complicated MVVM pattern example, it can be hard coded, it should just save the developer the time of creating all the CRUD code and forms and authorization necessary for users to edit the data. The developer could define 10 database tables, run the code generation, and then be pretty much 80% finished with any simple database application he wanted to make.

All of that would be generic code so I would think some framework like this would exist or someone would be working on some open source project like this already.

Does anyone know of a framework or tool like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Silverlight, but [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata/) sounds like it would do what you're asking.  It provides a web-based front end for editing database tables.

I've used it for a small project and you can literally have it up and running with CRUD functionality within an hour.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should take a look at the [Sculpture](http://www.codeplex.com/Sculpture) project. There might be something you are looking for.

Comment: thanks, looks interesting, but can't install it because it requires Microsoft's "Guidance Automation Extensions" which cannot install because it "rolls back because of an error", :-(

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot have direct connection to a database server with Silverlight, you should look at a .NET data access framework using the regular .NET Framework thru a Web Service.